# If for $x \in R$, $\phi (x)$ denotes the integer closest to $x$ ,then $\int_{10}^{12}\phi (x)dx$ equals to

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was thinking about the following problem:

If for $x \in R$, $\phi (x)$ denotes the integer closest to $x$ (If there are two such integers take the larger one),then $\int_{10}^{12}\phi (x)dx$ equals to

> (a)$22$
>   (b)$11$
>   (c)$20$
>   (d)$12$.

I do not know how to proceed with the problem. Could someone point me in the right direction.Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the function $\varphi$ on the interval $[10,12]$ as follows:

$$\varphi(x)=\begin{cases}
10,&\text{if }10\le x<10.5\\
11,&\text{if }10.5\le x<11.5\\
12,&\text{if }11.5\le x\le 12\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\int_{10}^{12}\varphi(x)\,dx=\int_{10}^{10.5}10\,dx+\int_{10.5}^{11.5}11\,dx+\int_{11.5}^{12}12\,dx\;,$$

which is a straightforward calculation.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.I have got it.

Comment: @user53386: You’re very welcome; I’m glad that it helped.