# Find integration of box function

Tags: real-analysis

Find integration of $$\int_{-2}^{2}\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor~dx$$ where $\lfloor . \rfloor$ is Box function i.e. greatest integer function . More explicitely  [x]= greatest integer not greater than x.

Comment: Your "Box function" is formally called the "[floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)".

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261482/if-for-x-in-r-phi-x-denotes-the-integer-closest-to-x-then-int-10) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Oops! Is that the floor function? Then I shall erase my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-2}^{2}\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^{2}\lfloor x^2-1\rfloor\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_0^1-1\,\mathrm{d}x
+2\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}0\,\mathrm{d}x
+2\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt3}1\,\mathrm{d}x
+2\int_{\sqrt3}^22\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=-2+2(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)+4(2-\sqrt3)\\[12pt]
&=6-2\sqrt2-2\sqrt3
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I got it.